# see the parametrized value in hibernate logs instead of?

Tags: hibernate

I have an java application in which I have to enable the hibernate logging to see the parameter values rite now in log I can see the ? , so instead of this I WANT TO SEE the real parameters passed in to thw query,

I have configured the following way

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACEThe first is equivalent to hibernate.show_sql=true, the second prints the bound parameters among other things.


hibernate.cfg.xml
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

but the query is that in parrent logger it is also written as ..

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=@log4j.appender.Hibernate.Threshold@, Hibernate
```

which when I search found the value..I have set it to debug as shown below

```
log4j.appender.Hibernate.Threshold=DEBUG
```

buit still in hibernate logs I see the query having the parametrs like ?
please advise how to see the actual parameters in log

Answer (score 0):

In my log4j.properties I have :

```
# Logs the JDBC parameters passed to a query
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
# logs the SQL statements
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

They enable hibernate log sql statements as well as data (instead of ?)

Comment: Volodymyr Levytskyi couldn't get completely please explain in detail the issue is that sql sataement are not logged I can see the ? in that place

Comment: For me these two lines in log4j.properties mean that hibernate logs generated queries + values(instead of ?) used in query. This means that instead of INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?,?) you will have in consle smth like INSERT INTO user VALUES(1,"firstName","lastName")